# Output of code in Javascript

Tags: javascript

As per hoisting concept, when this code snippet is run, all variable declarations are moved to top of code by compiler.So passed variable value 7 should be used instead of 2. Kindly explain the behavior.

```
var passed = 2;

var addTo = function() {
var inner = 3;
return inner + passed;
}

var addTo = function() {
var inner = 5;
alert(inner + " " + passed);
return inner + passed;
}


console.log(addTo());
var passed = 7;

O/P : 5 2
Intended O/P 5 7
```

Comment: because you assigned value 7 later in code. value assignment will be at its correct place

Comment: `As per hoisting concept` - declaration is hoisted, not assigned value!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hoisting variables in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246124/hoisting-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

In Below var passed = 7 is never hoisted since it is an initialization

```
console.log(addTo());
var passed = 7;
```

So you should log your function after initialization

```
var passed = 7;
console.log(addTo());
```

Comment: Updated as your notice

Comment: No you didnt refresh your page I guess because I provided the link before that answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because only the declaration (var passed ), not the initialization (=7) is hoisted to the top. JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp for more details.