# module.exports.variable vs module.exports={variable}

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, node-modules

`module.exports.variable` vs `module.exports={variable}`

Consider the code below from fileOne.js

```
module.exports = {
    x,
    v
}

async function v(){
    return "v"
}

var x = "x"
```

fileTwo.js

```
const y = require('./fileOne');

console.log(y.x, y.v());
// returns undefined and "v".
```

If I change fileOne.js code to:

```
module.exports = {
    //x,
    v
}

async function v(){
    return "v"
}
module.exports.x = "x"
```

... the code from `fileTwo.js` logs `x` and `v` to the console.

What is the difference between `module.exports.variable` and `module.exports={variable}` and why does the former work for variables but the latter does not?

Comment: ...The difference isn't really in the syntax of your exports - it's just the age old [hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting) at play. When you export `x` *before* you assign it, you get just that - an `undefined` because the assignment hasn't run yet. Function hoisting with `v` *will* ensure declaration + assignment happens before referencing the variable. When you do `module.exports.x = "x"` then you export the assigned value. If you move `module.exports = {x, v}` to the *bottom* of the file, it will work correctly.

Comment: Related: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859) | [Difference between variable declaration syntaxes in Javascript (including global variables)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4862193) | [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420) | [Hoisting variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36246124) | [Order of hoisting in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28246589)

Comment: @VLAZ Your comments have made me understand it really well. Thank you.