# Why JavaScript cannot hoist initialization?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I am studying hoisting concept now, but i cannot understand why
hoisting can only work on declaration, not initialization.

**declaration** O

```
catName("cat");

function catName(name){
  console.log(name) // return cat
}
```

**initialization** X

```
console.log(num); // return undefined
var num;
num = 6;
```

Comment: I'm guessing you got these examples from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hoisting variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246124/hoisting-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

> ...why hoisting can only work on declaration, not initialization

It ***can*** work with initialization (and in fact, that `var` variable *is* initialized — with the value `undefined`), it's just that hoisting the initializer expression is not defined for `var`. Hoisting initialization *is* defined for function declarations: The binding (loosely, *variable*) for the function is both declared *and* initialized with the function object:

```js
console.log(example); // Shows the function

function example() {
}
```

It's just that that's not how `var` is defined, not least because hoisting the initialization expression (rather than `undefined`) would be much more complicated than hoisting the initialization of a function identifier, because `var` initializers can be any arbitrary expression. So instead, `var` variables are initialized with `undefined`.

Fast-forward several years and the initialization of `let`, `const`, and `class` aren't hoisted at all (only the declaration), leading us to the Temporal Dead Zone between declaration and initialization during which you can't access them, because that was deemed more useful than hoisting `undefined`:

```js
console.log(example); // ReferenceError

let example = 42;
```